# Deploy an account-wide read-only SSH key onto GitHub

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I have an SSH server that I share with friends. We use it to connect to our GitHubs. Now I've generated an SSH keypair on it, and would like to add `id_rsa.pub` to my account, **with R/O access to all my repositories** (and future repos) (and my friends will repeat this). The problem is, I can't find a checkbox that reads "Make this key read-only", which is supposed to appear in the blue circle. Can I?

[image: GitHub screenshot]
Oh, yes. With that key it should be able to read all my repositories, as well as new repos that are created after adding the key without changing more settings (i.e. Once-And-For-All).

The requirement isn't that complicated. I just want a once-and-for-all solution, no matter how complex it is.

Comment: Only deploy keys support different read/write access. If you are in an Organization, it may be possible to attach the SSH key to a read-only user.

Comment: @osowskit Is it a once-and-for-all solution? There's no problem for me to create a new organization for my friends and I and upload the key to the organization.

Comment: If a shared SSH key is associated with a user account that only has read-only permissions, then yes. However, sharing SSH keys seems like a bad idea. You are better off adding their GitHub accounts to a team in your organization that only has read-only access.